# Problem inserting figure when not specifying float positioning and using babel

Tags: floats, positioning, babel

The example below reproduces the problem: instead of inserting the image `a.png`, the text `,ü,` appears. Commenting the line for babel package or inserting the optional positional argument for the figure, it works fine.  Is it a bug in babel?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{a.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You get the same output using instead `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png}` ?

Comment: @SimonDispa Yes. Using ```example-image-a``` as well. Any image.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can not reproduce the issue.

Comment: It works for me too. Maybe there is something wrong with your installation.

Comment: I'm using Babel 2020/02/14 3.40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an current version of babel  `babel.sty    2021/07/22 3.63 The Babel package` I can compile the following MWE without problems.

**Update your TeX distribution ...**

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: version ```2021/01/26 3.53``` worked as well